# RIA development - alternative for Adobe's Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

The platform to build on is only a 60 day trial
https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder

If i want to continue development need to pay money?

Is there any other alternative and is adobe flex the best way to build rich internet application going forward?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone has given a complete answer yet, so I'll give it a shot.

> If i want to continue development need
>   to pay money?

No; you are free to write code in any editor you wish, including NotePad or other text editor.  Then you can compile it with the [command line compiler](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_03.html) that is included as part of the [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK;jsessionid=518A0066B135BB15488E8AE5DF4A25FB).

> Is there any other alternative

There are plenty of alternatives to Flash Builder for building Flex applications.  Here are the ones I'm aware of:

- [FDT](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://fdt.powerflasher.com/&rct=j&q=FDT&ei=FVvHTcDRKIP10gG-hbj9Bw&usg=AFQjCNGtfnzURQYauDGZC-9rGmXQVhRpNQ&cad=rja) (An Eclipse Based IDE)
- [IntelliJ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/&rct=j&q=IntelliJ&ei=JlvHTf_UOePy0gGG17iACA&usg=AFQjCNF5HA_WodXGzI5OKtfhBRYkTvaRPA&cad=rja) (A populare IDE w/ Java Developers that has awesome Flex support)
- [Amethyst](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Blog/Amethyst-Flex-Debugger&rct=j&q=Amethyst%20Flex&ei=RVvHTc2TPOfg0QGhw-iVDg&usg=AFQjCNHWEencNIeVaH7t1C6L7IKA_FLWAQ&cad=rja) (A Visual Studio Plugin)
- [Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml) (A Visual Studio Plugin)

There are also other ActionScript IDEs, with [FlashDevelop](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://www.flashdevelop.org/&rct=j&q=FlashDevelop&ei=wlvHTZW7KJKG0QHI_cD_Bw&usg=AFQjCNHKKRsR8VDMmQ-zaJcSCuwLTK6LgA&cad=rja) being one I hear consistently good things about.  I do not know how easily it supports the Flex Framework, though.

> is adobe flex the best way to build
>   rich internet application going
>   forward?

Best is very subjective; and will depend upon a great many things that you have not told us, including--but not limited to--target platforms, user base, and in house knowledge.

Some common alternatives to Flex/Flash are:

- Silverlight:  The Microsoft competitor to Flash
- HTML(5)/JavaScript(AJAX): Using JavaScript to modify the DOM page and make remote requests.

However, it depends what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're student or unemployment you can get Flash Builder 4 Standard for free [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/free/).

Comment: [Free Flash Builder for Education offer concluded.](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder-free-ria-tools.edu.html)

Answer (score 1):

Flex itself is open source so you can use it free of charge. You can [download the SDK from Adobe here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flex_framework/).
This will allow you to develop flex applications with any editor and compile it on the command line.
This of course is no where near as comfortable or convenient as using Flash Builder. There is a port of Flash Builder 4 to linux called [fb4linux](http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/) which I use. It is very good but doesn't have all the features, although it is functional enough to be very useful. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent for mac or windows, but if not you could always run [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) in a [virtual machine](http://www.virtualbox.org/) in seamless mode and you'd barely notice the difference. You'll need to install [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)( not through the package manager) which requires [installing the official sun java](http://www.clickonf5.org/linux/how-install-sun-java-ubuntu-1004-lts/7777) (through the package manager). Quite a lot of work though but here are [some instructions](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/78818.aspx)

Comment: Wow; I never heard of fb4linux before.  Is it legit?

Comment: Appears to be legal. It's been cobbled together from stuff that Adobe have released.

Answer (score 1):

As far as free IDEs go, I have heard that [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) works for Flex development and it is free, though I have not used it.  There are other IDEs out there, like Idea, but they are not free.  There is a free plug-in for Visual Studio called [Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml), but you need Visual Studio (not free for plug-ins) to make it work.

I know a lot of people are having a lot of luck using Emacs or Vim along with Ant scripts for building projects.  Since the SDK is free, this is certainly an option.

Finally, there is another platform out there for Rich Internet Applications that does have a free IDE: [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/).  From a feature comparison, it is extremely similar to Flex and solves the same problems.  You can install the ["Web Platform Installer"](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=silverlight4tools;silverlight4toolkit;riaservicestoolkit) which includes [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/).  VWDE is a free IDE, and it is basically a subset of Visual Studio.

Good luck!